# Django templates condition check

Tags: python, django

All,

Can t we do the following in templates

{% if subject.id == selected_id %}

and also cannot we assign variable like {{selected="selected"}}

Thank........

Comment: Where in the Django documentation did you see that you could do this?  I've never seen this in the documents.  Can you provide a link?

Comment: Look, I'm not on the "kill the newbie" crowd. But you consistently ask questions that can be answered by a simple google search or by just reading the documentation. Every single question you ask someone points you to the docs and you seem to refuse to go read it. It has gotten to a point where I don't even read your questions anymore... I'm sure others feel the same way. SO is no substitute for the docs of whatever technology you are using. For the sake of actually getting good answers in the future - read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comparison will work in Django 1.2. For 1.1 you have to use [ifequal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal):

```
{% ifequal subject.id  selected_id %}
```

For variable assignment you can use [with](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with).

```
{% with selected as 'selected' %}

{% endwith %}
```

Don't hesitate to read the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/builtins/), it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Not as shown. Use the `ifequal` and `with` template tags instead.